# How to create x in x empty PNG file in Python?

Tags: python, png, zlib

I followed [this](https://garethrees.org/2007/11/14/pngcrush/#:%7E:text=A%20detailed%20look%20at%20the,PNG%2C%20only%2067%20bytes%20long.) tutorial to create 1x1 PNG file in Python. But I don't know how can I create 2x2, 3x3, ... PNG files.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3 -B

import struct
import zlib

def a(x, y):
    return (
        struct.pack('>I', len(y)) +
        x +
        y +
        struct.pack('>I', zlib.crc32(x + y))
    )

class png:
    def create():
        png = (
            b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1A\n' +
            a(b'IHDR', struct.pack('>IIBBBBB', 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)) +
            a(b'IDAT', zlib.compress(struct.pack('>BB', 0, 0))) +
            a(b'IEND', b'')
        )
        return png

f = open("file.png", "wb")
f.write(png.create())
f.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show your attempt.

Comment: Sigh. No. What did you try to get 2x2, 3x3? You don't come to stackoverflow unless you have tried and run into a problem.